# Bug : my each loop works only when I write <%= debug ...%>

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I have an odd problem, I converted an xml string to hash with simpleXML.

But when I try to loop inside the sub hash or array 'properties', it doesn't work, here is the HASH :

```
{
  "softwares" => { "type" =>"text", "multiple" =>"true" },
  "edition_first_date" => { "type" =>"date" },
  "edition_last_date" => { "type" =>"date" },
  "documents_date_begin" => { "type" =>"date" },
  "documents_date_end" => { "type" =>"date" },
  "data_collection_date_begin" => { "type" =>"date" },
  "data_collection_date_end" => { "type" =>"date" },
  "rec_id" => { "type" =>"hidden" },
  "title" => { "type" =>"text", "multiple" =>"false" },
  "documents_count" => { "type" =>"hidden" },
  "archive_extent" => { "type" =>"text", "multiple" =>"false" },
  "archive_location" => { "type" =>"text", "multiple" =>"false" },
  "access_conditions" => { "type" =>"text", "multiple" =>"true" },
  "association" => {
    "name" =>"distributors",
    "label" =>"distributors",
    "properties" => { "property" => [
      { "name" =>"person_distributors", "class_name" =>"Person" },
      { "name" =>"orgunit_distributors", "class_name" =>"Orgunit" }
    ] }
  }
}
```

Here is my template code, when I try to loop in the property, it only takes the first property, I dunno why, and when I add <%= debug v['properties']['property']%> it takes all the property..., it's very odd.

```
<% studyHash['step1'].each do |k, v|%>
    <% if k == 'association' %>

        <div id="<%=v['label']%>">

            <h4><%=v['label']%></h4>

            <a class="add-<%=v['label']%>" data-toggle="modal">add</a

            <%= debug v['properties']['property']%>

            <% v['properties']['property'].each do |k|%>

                <%=k%>

                <%=link_to_add_association(' ', f, k['name'].to_sym, :partial=>'/studies/'+k['class_name'].to_s().downcase+'_fields', :data => {"association-insertion-method" => "append" })%>

            <%end%>

        </div>
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing `</a>` tag in line 8:

```
 <a class="add-<%=v['label']%>" data-toggle="modal">add</a
```

Comment: Wow thank you.
The problem was the <a> tag not closed, now it works. I has a similar problem with nokogiri but now I think the cause is the same error.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome, updated my answer. Might as well accept it if it solved your problem.